# Map Only loaded when its Activity is Launcher Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Map activity is not working when it is not launcher activity also i have to remove *name=MyApplication*  from application tag to make it work. Activity opens but not map is not loaded if i open it from other class.

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.byteshaft.medicosperuanos">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="true">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity android:name=".introscreen.IntroScreen">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".accountfragments.AccountManagerActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".doctors.DoctorDetailsActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".patients.DoctorsAppointment"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".patients.DoctorsLocator"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".patients.DoctorsRoute"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".patients.PatientsRecentHistory"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".patients.PatientDetails"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".patients.DoctorBookingActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".patients.CreateAppointmentActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".messages.ConversationActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
</application>
```

**MapsActivity**

```
package com.byteshaft.medicosperuanos;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

**layout file(activity_maps)**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.byteshaft.medicosperuanos.patients.DoctorsRoute" />
```

**AppGlobals**

```
package com.byteshaft.medicosperuanos.utils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.byteshaft.medicosperuanos.R;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
```

public class AppGlobals extends Application {

```
private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";
private static Context sContext;
public static final String IS_DOCTOR = "is_medicosperuanos";
public static Typeface typefaceBold;
public static Typeface typefaceNormal;
public static Typeface robotoBlack;
public static Typeface robotoBlackItalic;
public static Typeface robotoBold;
public static Typeface robotoBoldItalic;
public static Typeface robotoItalic;
public static Typeface robotoLight;
public static Typeface robotoLightItalic;
public static Typeface robotoMedium;
public static Typeface robotoMediumItalic;
public static Typeface robotoRegular;
public static Typeface robotoThin;
public static Typeface robotoThinItalic;
public static final String SERVER_IP = "https:.......";
public static final String BASE_URL = String.format("%s/api/", SERVER_IP);
public static final String REVIEW_URL = BASE_URL + "public/medicosperuanos/%s/review";
public static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "user_name";
public static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
public static final String KEY_PROFILE_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
public static final String KEY_DOC_SPECIALITY = "speciality";
public static final String KEY_DOC_ID = "identity_document";
public static final String KEY_COLLEGE_ID = "college_id";
public static final String KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH = "dob";
public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE_URL = "photo";
public static final String SERVER_PHOTO_URL = "server_photo_url";
public static final String KEY_LOGIN = "login";
public static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_PRIMARY = "phone_number_primary";
public static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_SECONDARY = "phone_number_secondary";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "account_type";
public static final String KEY_USER_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_AFFILIATE_CLINIC = "affiliate_clinic";
public static final String KEY_CHAT_STATUS = "available_to_chat";
public static final String KEY_INSURANCE_CARRIER = "insurance_carrier";
public static final String KEY_EMERGENCY_CONTACT = "emergency_contact";
public static final String KEY_SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE = "subscription_plan";
public static final String KEY_CONSULTATION_TIME = "consultation_time";
public static final String KEY_REVIEW_STARS = "review_stars";
public static final String KEY_SHOW_NEWS = "show_news";
public static final String KEY_SHOW_NOTIFICATION = "show_notification";
public static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
public static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
public static final String KEY_USER = "user";
public static final String KEY_GOT_INFO = "got_info";
public static final String KEY_FAVOURITE_STATE = "favourite";
public static final String KEY_STATE_SELECTED = "selected_state";
public static final String KEY_CITY_SELECTED = "selected_city";
public static final String KEY_SUBSCRIPTION_SELECTED = "selected_subscription";
public static final String KEY_CLINIC_SELECTED = "selected_clinic";
public static final String KEY_SPECIALIST_SELECTED = "selected_specialist";
public static final String KEY_INSURANCE_SELECTED = "selected_insurance";

public static final String PENDING = "pending";
public static final String ACCEPTED = "accepted";
public static final String REJCTED = "rejected";


public static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";
public static final String USER_ACTIVATION_KEY = "activation_key";
public static final int LOCATION_ENABLE = 3;
public static ImageLoader sImageLoader;
public static final int CALL_PERMISSION = 4;

public static boolean isDoctorFavourite = false;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    disableSSLCertificateChecking();
    sImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    sImageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext()));
    sContext = getApplicationContext();
    typefaceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/bold.ttf");
    typefaceNormal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/normal.ttf");
    robotoBlack = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Black.ttf");
    robotoBlackItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_BlackItalic.ttf");
    robotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Bold.ttf");
    robotoBoldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_BoldItalic.ttf");
    robotoItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Italic.ttf");
    robotoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Light.ttf");
    robotoLightItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_LightItalic.ttf");
    robotoMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Medium.ttf");
    robotoMediumItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_MediumItalic.ttf");
    robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Regular.ttf");
    robotoThin = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Thin.ttf");
    robotoThinItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_ThinItalic.ttf");
}

private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }
            }
    };

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
            return s.equals("46.101.34.116");
        }
    });

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void loginState(boolean type) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_LOGIN, type).apply();
}

public static boolean isLogin() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_LOGIN, false);
}

public static void userType(boolean type) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, type).apply();
}

public static boolean isDoctor() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, false);
}

public static void saveChatStatus(boolean state) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_CHAT_STATUS, state).apply();
}

public static boolean isOnline() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_CHAT_STATUS, false);
}

public static void saveNotificationState(boolean state) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_SHOW_NOTIFICATION, state).apply();
}

public static boolean isShowNotification() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_SHOW_NOTIFICATION, false);
}

public static void saveNewsState(boolean state) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_SHOW_NEWS, state).apply();
}

public static boolean isShowNews() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_SHOW_NEWS, false);
}

public static void saveFavourite(String drId, boolean isFavourite) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(drId, isFavourite).apply();
}

public static boolean isFavourite(String id) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(id, false);
}

public static SharedPreferences getPreferenceManager() {
    return getContext().getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static void clearSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply();
}

public static void saveDataToSharedPreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
}

public static String getStringFromSharedPreferences(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
}

public static void firstTimeLaunch(boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, value).apply();
}

public static boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, false);
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return sContext;
}

public static void alertDialog(Activity activity, String title, String msg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.MyAlertDialogTheme);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

public static void gotInfo(boolean type) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_GOT_INFO, type).apply();
}

public static boolean isInfoAvailable() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_GOT_INFO, false);
}

public static void saveDoctorProfileIds(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(key, value).apply();
}

public static int getDoctorProfileIds(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, -1);
}

public static void buttonEffect(View button) {
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0D1D1D1, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Show your error log here If you are getting and you haven't added meta data for your play service version in manifest file.

Comment: there is no error. No error i have done quite debugging myself

Comment: logs when i open map activity https://paste.ubuntu.com/24425296/

Comment: add meta data for google play service version in your manifest file: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> and then try

Comment: see guys if i make the map activity launcher and remove name element from application  android:name=".utils.AppGlobals" its working else not. let me update my code from appGlobals as well. A sec

Comment: @Bhavnik Not working. i update my Application class please check if there is something which causing issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have disableSSLCertificateChecking method in AppGlobals, thats why map was not working.

Comment: Very Strange, I've never faced any issue with map like this

Answer (score 0):

try this in layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this help you;

Answer (score 0):

you should change android:context to

```
tool:contex="your path.MapsActivity"/>
```

Comment: in layout of MapsActivity ?

Comment: it is tools:context=''MapsActivity' as i know.

Comment: yup its tools:context you can change it and then try

Comment: Not working current logs i see warning i guess https://paste.ubuntu.com/24425380/